# SQLite taking user id and data from activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two tables in DataBaseHelper Activity one for user and one to log measurements from 5 diffenrent activities. My DataBaseHelper has the addreaiding(); to take the data. Here is the code from DataHelper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UserManager.db";

    // User table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // Reading table name
    private static final String TABLE_READING = "reading";

    // User Table Columns names
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD = "user_password";

    //Readings Table Columns names

    private static final String COLUMN_READING_USERREFERENCE = "reading_user_reference";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_DATETIME = "reading_datetime";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT = "reading_weight";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_AGE = "reading_age";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT = "reading_height";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_CALORIES_ = "reading_calories";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_BMR = "reading_bmr";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_BMI = "reading_bmi";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_BF = "reading_bf";
    private static final String COLUMN_READING_FFMI = "reading_ffmi";




    // create table users sql query
    private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" + ")";

    // create table readings sql query
    private static final String CREATE_READING_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_READING +
                    "(" +
                    COLUMN_READING_USERREFERENCE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                    COLUMN_READING_DATETIME + " TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                    COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT + " INTEGER," +
                    COLUMN_READING_AGE + " INTEGER , "+
                    COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT + " INTEGER," +
                    COLUMN_READING_CALORIES_ + " REAL," +
                    COLUMN_READING_BMR + " REAL," +
                    COLUMN_READING_BMI + " REAL," +
                    COLUMN_READING_BF + " REAL , "+
                    COLUMN_READING_FFMI + " REAL "+
                    ")";


    // drop table sql query
    private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER;
    private String DROP_READING_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_READING;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_READING_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        //Drop User Table if exist
        db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DROP_READING_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    /**
     * This method is to create user record
     *
     * @param user
     */
    public void addUser(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());





        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    public long addReading(int userreference, long datetime, int age,int weight,int height, double calories,
            double bmi, double bmr, double bf, double ffmi) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_USERREFERENCE,userreference);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_DATETIME,sdf.format(datetime));
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_AGE,age);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_WEIGHT,weight);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_HEIGHT,height);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_CALORIES_,calories);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_BMR,bmr);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_BMI,bmi);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_BF,bf);
        cv.put(COLUMN_READING_FFMI,ffmi);
        return db.insert(TABLE_READING,null,cv) ;
    }
```

I have two major problems. Firts how  ill take user ID after user logging as userreference key in the READINGS TABLE and second how to use the addreading in my activities to take the data. As an example this is Calories Activity from where i need date, age,height,weight, and calories result. I assume that the other fields (bmr,bmi,bf) should be default 0.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import eu.healthydev.bodymeasure.R;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Calories extends BaseActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    Spinner sp, goal_sp;
    double valofactlevel = 0;
    int goalnum = 0;
    Calendar calander;
    SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat;
    String Date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calories);
        TextView cal_pound_to_gram = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cal_pounds_view);
        EditText weight_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_weight_num);

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper  = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.addReading(  );




        if (MainActivity.unit_is_gram){
            cal_pound_to_gram.setText("Kilograms");
        }

        if(MainActivity.unit_is_meter){
            TextView cal_inches_to_cent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cal_inches_view);
            cal_inches_to_cent.setText("Centimeters");
            //cal_inches_to_cent.setWidth(200);
            EditText cent_num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cal_inches_num);
            cent_num.setWidth(595);
            TextView cal_feet_to_meter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cal_feet_view);
            cal_feet_to_meter.setText(""); //meters
            EditText cal_disappear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cal_feet_num);
            cal_disappear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }

        Button resetButt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cal_reset_button);
        resetButt.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        EditText weight_num_reset = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_age_num);
                        weight_num_reset.setText(null);

                        EditText waist_num_reset = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_weight_num);
                        waist_num_reset.setText(null);

                        EditText wrist_num_reset = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_feet_num);
                        wrist_num_reset.setText(null);

                        EditText hip_num_reset = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_inches_num);
                        hip_num_reset.setText(null);

                        TextView bf_answer_reset = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal_answer);
                        bf_answer_reset.setText("");


                    }
                }
        );


        sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cal_actlevel_list);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.levelofact,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        goal_sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cal_goal_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter goal_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.goalsarr,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        goal_sp.setAdapter(goal_adapter);
        goal_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Button calculate_calories_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calc_calories_button);
        calculate_calories_button.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        EditText age_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_age_num);
                        String age_s = (age_num.getText().toString());
                        double age;
                        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(age_s)){
                            age_num.setError("Field can't be empty");
                            age = 0;
                            return;
                        }
                        age = Integer.parseInt(age_num.getText().toString());


                        EditText weight_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_weight_num);
                        String weight_s = (weight_num.getText().toString());
                        double weight = 0;
                        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(weight_s)){
                            weight_num.setError("Field can't be empty");
                            weight = 0;
                            return;
                        }
                        weight = Integer.parseInt(weight_num.getText().toString());

                        double feet = 0;
                        if (!MainActivity.unit_is_meter){
                            EditText feet_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_feet_num);
                            String feet_s = feet_num.getText().toString();

                            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(feet_s) && !MainActivity.unit_is_meter){
                                feet_num.setError("Field can't be empty");
                                feet = 0;
                                return;
                            }
                            feet = Integer.parseInt(feet_num.getText().toString());
                        }

                        EditText inch_num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cal_inches_num);
                        String inch_s = inch_num.getText().toString();
                        double inches;
                        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(inch_s)){
                            inch_num.setError("Field can't be empty");
                            inches = 0;
                            return;
                        }
                        inches = Integer.parseInt(inch_num.getText().toString());

                        RadioGroup rad_group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.cal_radioGroup);
                        int check = rad_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        if (check == -1){
                            Toast.makeText(Calories.this, "Select gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        RadioButton fem_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cal_fem_button);
                        boolean fem = fem_button.isChecked();

                        RadioButton male_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cal_male_button);
                        boolean male = male_button.isChecked();

                        TextView calResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal_answer);
                        double bmrr = doCalories(fem, male, age, weight, feet, inches);
                        bmrr = (bmrr*valofactlevel)+goalnum;
                        String bmrstring = "";
                        bmrstring = String.valueOf(Math.round(bmrr));
                        if (goalnum == 0){
                            bmrstring = bmrstring.concat(" calories to maintain weight.");
                        }
                        else if (goalnum > 0){
                            bmrstring = bmrstring.concat(" calories to gain weight.");
                        }
                        else if (goalnum < 0){
                            bmrstring = bmrstring.concat(" calories to lose weight.");
                        }

                        if (check != -1){
                            calResult.setText(bmrstring);
                        }


                    }
                }


        );
    }

    public double doCalories(boolean fem, boolean male, double age, double weight, double feet, double inches){

        double bmrResult = 0;
        double height_in_inches;

        if (MainActivity.unit_is_gram){
            weight = weight * 2.2;
        }

        if (MainActivity.unit_is_meter){
            height_in_inches = 0.39370* inches; //actually is 0.39370 * centimeters
        }

        else height_in_inches = (feet*12)+inches;

        if (fem == true) {
            //if it is a female use this formula
            bmrResult = 10*(weight/2.2)+6.25*(height_in_inches*2.54)-5*age-161;
        }

        else if (male == true){
            //if it is a male use this formula

            bmrResult = 10*(weight/2.2)+6.25*(height_in_inches*2.54)-5*age+5;
        }

        calander = Calendar.getInstance();
        simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date = simpledateformat.format(calander.getTime());

        return bmrResult;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Spinner one = (Spinner)parent;

        if(one.getId() == R.id.cal_actlevel_list){
            TextView myText = (TextView) view;
            if (position == 0) valofactlevel = 1.2;
            else if (position == 1) valofactlevel = 1.375;
            else if (position == 2) valofactlevel = 1.55;
            else if (position == 3) valofactlevel = 1.725;
            else if (position == 4) valofactlevel = 1.9;
        }
        else if(one.getId() == R.id.cal_goal_spinner){
            if (position == 0){
                goalnum = 0;
            }
            else if (position == 1){
                goalnum = -500;
            }
            else if (position == 2){
                goalnum = 500;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        //Toast.makeText(this,"Select activity level ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

I would apriciate any help considering that i m new in android and totally beginner in SQLite. The part of SQLite whith the fantastic help from @MikeT

Answer (score 0):

think you may use userreference key from Reading Table as user ID in User Table instead id autoincrement. It is one to one relationship: one user - one measuring

Comment: I think its the opposite. I need to take User Id as userreference. This is my first major problem. And its not one to one as one user can have different measures in different dates.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

Problem 1: You can use user_id as foreign key in reading table.

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES TABLE_USER(user_id)
```

Problem 2: Update data or you can write data also to reading table

```
                userId = // id of the user //

                ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
                Values.put(COLUMN_READING_CALORIES, 500);
                            //...
                getContext().getContentResolver().update(TABLE_READING.CONTENT_URI,
                        Values,
                        TABLE_READING.user_id + " = " + userId,
                        null);
```

I suggest you to use [Room lib](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) as its the new successor